Nestjs server automatically reloaded after some period in Vercel Deployment
I uploaded my Nestjs project in the Vercel Deployment. I'm using session in my project, but for some reason the server sends me 401 even though the time was way before than the expire date. I checked session configurations and there were no mistakes that I made, and it was totally fine when I tested in localhost.
So I checked the log in vercel and I found a problem that when I make a request after some period, say 20min, they reload my Nestjs automatically so that the server regards my session as a invalid one.
Why and how this kind of problem can be occurred? or Are there any possible mistakes that I made?
Thanks in advance!

Vercel is a serverless platform. If you are saving items in the memory, it is unlikely that it will be there after a few minutes or even seconds. Use a database or external solution to persist the state of your app.
